# Cloud Storage Class B Operations

Tags: android, firebase

I am using FireBase and I got a `StorageException`:

```
java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 402,    "message": "Quota has been exceeded for this project. Please visit the Firebase pricing page to learn more."  }}
    at bmm.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC@11518470:149)
    at bmm.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC@11518470:81)
    at bmg.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC@11518470:8)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:499)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzed.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.acb.zzhM(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.acf.zze(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.abu.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.zzb.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

When I went to [quota usages](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/quotadetails) on my console page, it showed me this:

[image]

**So what is *Cloud Storage Class B Operations*?**

At the moment the app is in development and haven't been released yet, this usage is of my emulator solely.

Luckily I got file logs and I can see that I sent exactly 37 requests for file with size of 0.56 MB. And 97 requests for token.

Is token request are taking from storage count too?

This quota thing doesn't looks right.